# Unix find: list of files from stdin

Tags: bash, unix, find

I'm working in Linux & bash (or Cygwin & bash).

I have a huge--*huge*--directory structure, and I have to find a few needles in the haystack.

Specifically, I'm looking for these files (20 or so):

```
foo.c
bar.h
...
quux.txt
```

I know that they are in a subdirectory somewhere under `.`.

I know I can find any one of them with
`find . -name foo.c -print`.  This command takes a few minutes to execute.

How can I print the names of these files with their full directory name?  I don't want to execute 20 separate `find`s--it will take too long.

Can I give `find` the list of files from stdin?  From a file?  Is there a different command that does what I want?

Do I have to first assemble a command line for `find` with `-o` using a loop or something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your directory structure is huge but not changing frequently, it is good to run

```
cd /to/root/of/the/files
find . -type f -print > ../LIST_OF_FILES.txt #and sometimes handy the next one too
find . -type d -print > ../LIST_OF_DIRS.txt
```

after it you can really FAST find anything (with grep, sed, etc..) and update the file-lists only when the tree is changed. (it is a simplified replacement if you don't have `locate`)

So,

```
grep '/foo.c$' LIST_OF_FILES.txt #list all foo.c in the tree..
```

When want find a list of files, you can try the following:

```
fgrep -f wanted_file_list.txt < LIST_OF_FILES.txt
```

or directly with the find command

```
find . type f -print | fgrep -f wanted_file_list.txt
```

the `-f` for fgrep mean - read patterns from the file, so you can easily grepping input for multiple patterns...

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to run `find` twenty times.

You can construct a single command with a multiple of filename specifiers:

```
find . \( -name 'file1' -o -name 'file2' -o -name 'file3' \) -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: -exec echo {} \;
is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I'm used to a non-GNU version of `find` so I tend to be explicit. And if the `echo` is replaced with, for example, `printf` we can have much more control of the output.

Comment: So if there are 20 such files is there no alternative than to type `-o -name` 20 times? That doesn't take advantage of piping input from stdin or from a file.

Answer (score 2):

Is the `locate(1)` command an acceptable answer? Nightly it builds an index, and you can query the index quite quickly:

```
$ time locate id_rsa
/home/sarnold/.ssh/id_rsa
/home/sarnold/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

real    0m0.779s
user    0m0.760s
sys 0m0.010s
```

I gave up executing a similar `find` command in my home directory at 36 seconds. :)

If nightly doesn't work, you could run the `updatedb(8)` program by hand once before running `locate(1)` queries. `/etc/updatedb.conf` (`updatedb.conf(5)`) lets you select specific directories or filesystem types to include or exclude.

Comment: This does in principle what I want to do, and to get exactly what I want I could grep for my desired directory, but nightly doesn't work, and I don't have permissions for `updatedb`.

Comment: @JXG, don't overlook the `EXAMPLES` section of the manpage :) _To create a private mlocate database as an user other than root, run_ `updatedb -l 0 -o db_file -U source_directory`.

Comment: @JXG, ah, maybe you've got `slocate` on your system instead of `mlocate`. I would hope it too can maintain databases without being root.

Comment: it worked when I used the example you brought, but the directory structure has a lot of symlinks pointing all over the place.  Building a DB for the whole filesystem is just impractical, but more important, I wouldn't know which files are really mine, and which belong to someone else but happen to have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [assemble your command line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time).

Comment: And once I save the list of files in an array, use a loop to build the find command?  What is the best command line to use, under the circumstances?

Comment: You don't need to put the files in an array; just directly create the find command in an array and then call it.

Comment: er, how do you do that, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to process a list of files from stdin and assemble your (FreeBSD) find command to use extended regular expression matching `(n1|n2|n3)`.

For GNU find you may have to use one of the following options to enable extended regular expression matching:

`-regextype posix-egrep`

`-regextype posix-extended`

```
echo '
foo\\.c
bar\\.h
quux\\.txt
' | xargs bash -c '
IFS="|"; 
find -E "$PWD" -type f -regex "^.*/($*)$" -print
echo find -E "$PWD" -type f -regex "^.*/($*)$" -print
' arg0

# note: "$*" uses the first character of the IFS variable as array item delimiter
(
IFS='|'
set -- 1 2 3 4 5
echo "$*"   # 1|2|3|4|5
)
```