# List of files to check if present

Tags: linux, shell

I have a large list of files, and I need to check to see whether they are somewhere on my linux server. Some of them may be and some of them may not.

Is there a command line tool to do this?

Or must I resort to looping find in a shell script?

Comment: I can't tell for certain, but perhaps `locate` would help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix find: list of files from stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185994/unix-find-list-of-files-from-stdin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another alternative, which relies on using find. The idea is to run find once, save all the filenames and then compare them to the list of files.

First, the list of files must be sorted: let us called sortedFiles.txt

run

```
 find / -type f | xargs -n1 -I@ basename '@' | sort -u > /tmp/foundFiles.txt
```

now compare them, and print only those in the first file but not in the second

```
 comm -23 /tmp/sortedFiles.txt /tmp/foundFiles.txt
```

This will tell you the ones that are not in the computer.

if you want the ones in the computer then use:

```
 comm -12 /tmp/sortedFiles.txt /tmp/foundFiles.txt
```

this will tell you the ones that are in the computer. The disadvantage is that you don't know where they are. :)

Alternatively run find:

```
find / -type f > /tmp/allFiles.txt
```

then iterate using grep, making sure you match the end of the line from the last /

```
 cat /tmp/filesToFind.txt | xargs -n1 -I@ egrep '/@$' /tmp/allFiles.txt
```

This will print only the locations of the files found, but will not print those that are not found.

--dmg

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain, but I get a missing operand error when I try the ` find / -type f | basename | sort -u > /tmp/foundFiles.txt`. Something to with basename.

Comment: Since I couldn't get basename to work, I ended up doing some kind of bfind and grep comb but it worked well enough. Thanks

Comment: oh, sorry.  I should have used xargs before basename. I'll edit the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a list of filenames without path (all unique). I would suggest to use locate

assuming you have the file with the filenames: files.txt

```
cat files.txt | xargs -n1 -I@ locate -b '\@' | xargs -n1 -I@ basename @ | uniq > found.txt
```

then just diff the files.

```
diff files.txt found.txt
```

oh, one clarification. This will tell you if the files EXIST in your computer, not where :)

if you want to know where simple run:

```
cat files.txt | xargs -n1 -I@ locate -b '\@'
```

--dmg

Comment: Thanks. I appear to have run into a problem. I expect that if any of the files are present at all, they will be in a mounted network drive. I have tried to locate files that I know are there and it doesn't return anything, even when I cd to the directory of that file and re-run locate. Is this because the database that locate uses for all files doesn't look in the mnt folders?

Comment: locate might not be configured to scan the network drive. Look at the solution using find i posted. That might be the solution you need (although slower; locate is much more efficient, since it uses a database that it updates nightly).

Answer (score 0):

If you do the loop, it's better to use locate instead of find. It's faster!

If lista contains file names you can use:

```
cat lista | xargs locate
```